# What is the simplest function yielding Fibonacci numbers upon iteration?

Tags: computational-complexity, fibonacci-numbers, iterated-function-system

A while ago I asked a [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372240/can-all-inverse-trigonometric-functions-with-periodic-iterates-be-characterize) on trigonometric functions that are iteratively periodic. That is, after a finite number of iterations (compositions of the function with itself) the function returns to its original form. In other words, for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{>1}$ we have $f^{[k]} (x) = f^{[1]}(x) =: f(x)$.

In the question, I also mentioned some counterexamples that are *not* iteratively periodic. In these instances, I found functions that yield Fibonacci numbers upon iteration:

- Consider $m(x) := m^{[1]}(x) = \cot(\arcsin(x)) = \frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{x}$. Then, $m^{[n]}(x) = \sqrt{ \frac{F_{n} - F_{n+1}x^{2}}{F_{n}x^{2} - F_{n-1}} \cdot (-1)^{n+1} } $ for $n >1$, where $F_{n}$ is the $n$'th Fibonacci number.
- Define $l(x) := l^{[1]}(x) = \cos(\arctan(x)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}} $. In this case, $l^{[n]} (x) = \sqrt{\frac{F_{n} + F_{n-1}x^{2}}{F_{n+1} + F_{n}x^{2}}}$ for $n>1$.

**Question**: though $m(\cdot)$ and $l(\cdot)$ are not the most complex functions, I wonder whether there exist functions that are even simpler than these and generate fibonacci numbers as well upon iteration. On could consider a rigorous definition of function [complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations), but if that's not your thing then a simple function from a more intuitive sense (as little operations and inputs as possible) suffices as well. The function does not have to be trigonometric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $f(x) = 1+\frac{1}{x}$. Then $$f^{[n]}(x) = \frac{F_{n+1} x +F_n}{F_n x + F_{n-1}}$$

A related one is $g(x) = \frac{1}{1+x}$. Then $$g^{[n]}(x)=\frac{F_{n-1}x+F_n}{F_n x+F_{n+1}}$$

I doubt there are "simpler" functions that those two whose iterations involve Fibonacci numbers.

This functions also have other amusing properties, for example:

If you define $f^{[n]}(x)$ for $n<0$ as the iterations of the inverse function, and extend in the usual way the Fibonacci numbers to negative indices, the formula above remains valid.

We have $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} f^{[n]}(1) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F_{n+2}}{F_{n+1}}=\phi$, the golden ratio.